# Rotated imageview not appearing after addsubview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, rotation

I have added an arrow image view and I want to rotate it to create a corner.
My code is pretty simple:

```
[self.view addSubview:self.upLeftCorner];
self.upLeftCorner.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(2.35619449);
```

The imageview appears when i don't rotate it, however it does not after the rotation. I tried adding the subview after the rotation but still it does not appear. Any help?

Comment: Give your whole code. We need to know what you have in order to help

Comment: I have an AVC capture session started and I add imageviews as subviews and they appear. my viewdidLoad is huge and it will be very confusing. the only commands that  have to do with the imageview is those two. if I take away the transform then the imageview appears however if I transfer it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is working:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
[imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];

imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(2.35619449);

[self.view addSubview:imageView];
```

I think its because you did the `addSubview` before rotating the `imageView`. In my code, I rotated then `addSubview`

Comment: I tried doing it after but still the same result. this is crazy!

Comment: then its somewhere else in your code that is effecting this, i ran the above code. it worked